# Masculine words with umlaut-er plural

Tags: grammatical-number

I’ve read in a book that in German, there are only twelve masculine words that have a plural by adding umlaut and *-er*, one of them is the word: *Mann*, with the plural: *Männer*.
I want to be provided with all those 12 words, to memorise them, because it will make the plural of other words more predictable.

Comment: Word lists are regularly off-topic. But since this list is supposed to be clearly limited and it is well defined, not subjective, it does seem to be allowable. It could be phrased another way "Is the notion true", and the answer would still need to show the list, for what it's worth. Not clear why this had to be closed *after* three rather frequent contributers already found it worthwhile enough to answer. Alas I do not have the twelfth word to offer, so I shouldn't mouth-off.

Answer (score 6):

Zur Erleichterung des Überblicks sammle ich mal alle bisher genannten männlichen -er-Plural-mit-Umlaut-Wörter hier:

**A) Die reine Lehre: Singularform ohne -er und Umlaut**

1) der Reichtum, die Reichtümer

2) der Irrtum, die Irrtümer

3) der Gott, die Götter

4) der Rand, die Ränder

5) der Wurm, die Würmer

6) der Mund, die Münder

7) der Strauch, die Sträucher

8) der Balg, die Bälger

9) der Wald, die Wälder

10) der Mann, die Männer

11) der Schlund, die Schlünder (zu unterscheiden von *die Schlünde* oder *Schlunde* mit anderer Bedeutung; Achtung, strittig, siehe Kommentare)

12) ... ?

**B) Etwas weniger streng: auch die Singularform darf -er haben**

1) der Vater, die Väter

2) der Bruder, die Brüder

**C) Ganz schlampig: Umlaut ist schon im Singular vorhanden**

1) der Sünder, die Sünder

2) der Wärter, die Wärter

3) der Bräter, die Bräter (eine besondere Form von Topf)

4) der Müller, die Müller

5) der Knüller, die Knüller (spannende Nachricht)

6) der Füller, die Füller (Scheibgerät)

7) der Zünder, die Zünder (Teil einer Bombe)

**D) Thema verfehlt: kein Umlaut im Plural**

1) der Schreiner, die Schreiner

2) der Dachdecker, die Dachdecker

3) der Handwerker, die Handwerker

und weiter so bis ∞

Comment: Der Plural von Schlund ist laut [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Schlund) Schlünde oder Schlunde. Dafür fehlt natürlich noch Mann/Männer.

Comment: @IQV  *Schlünder* hat eine andere Bedeutung als *Schlünde*. Ein Vater mit vielen Kindern hat viele **Schlünder** zu füttern! - Ist so jedenfalls in der Belletristik durchaus zu finden. - Den Mann ergänze ich noch.

Comment: @IQV  Umlaut: oh, richtig. Ich hatte die Frage nicht gründlich genug gelesen. Danke.

Comment: Analog zum Vater gäbe es auch noch den Bruder (die Brüder), aber dann wären wir über der gesuchten Zahl von 12. Ich schätze mal, Wörter, die im Singular bereits auf -er enden, zählen nicht.

Comment: Aber schon lustig, wenn man bewusst darüber nachdenkt, dass Reichtum und Irrtum eigentlich "falsch" gebildet sind! Das fällt einem sonst nicht auf.

Comment: @Annatar ... womit der Vater ja auch wegfiele, und dann fehlte uns noch ein Wort... Ich nehme jetzt mal den Bruder noch auf; mal kucken, was noch passiert... Oh... huch... und da ist noch ein Problemkind: Der **Sünder**, dessen Plural ja alle Kriterien hier erfüllt... hmpf...

Comment: Habe große Probleme mit "Schlund - Schlünder". Ich kann online nur eine Referenz (außer Eigennamen) zu "Schlünder" finden, und da könnte es auch sein, dass der Schreiber einfach übertreibt oder sich vertut. Wenn der Duden keine Variante von "Schlund" mit Plural "Schlünder" hat, dann bezweifle ich doch wirklich, ob diese Form wirklich rchtig sein kann.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis. Ich verstehe die Bedenken. Hier erhebt sich dann halt die Frage, ab wann du eine Wortform als zulässig ansehen willst. Wenn sie in, sagen wir, einer gängigen Karl-May-Ausgabe vorkäme (und kein offensichtlicher Druckfehler wäre, sondern die vielen, vielen Redaktionen der May-Romane überstanden hätte) gälte sie dann? Auch wenn der Duden sie nicht verzeichnete? Oder gilt nur, was der Duden explizit verzeichnet?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Gegenfrage: würde dich das Ergebnis einer [Google Ngram-Abfrage](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Schl%C3%BCnde%2CSchlunde%2CSchl%C3%BCnder&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CSchl%C3%BCnde%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CSchlunde%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CSchl%C3%BCnder%3B%2Cc0) überzeugen?

Comment: @IQV - Ah, das ist interessant. Es belegt - immerhin! - das Vorkommen der Wortform, und es zeigt einen auffälligen Gipfel in der Zeit 1937-1950. Sollte *Schlünder* vor allem in Texten des Nationalsozialismus verwendet worden sein? - Unklar ist mir leider, auf welches Textkorpus sich diese Zählung stützt. Das muss ja alles was Digitalisiertes sein. Wären zum Beispiel Schulbücher aus jener Zeit heute überhaupt digitalisiert zugänglich? Zeitungen vielleicht ja schon...

Comment: Ich halte es aber für möglich, dass *Schlünder* auch wirklich nur vorkommt in der Formulierung *viele Schlünder zu füttern* und dass es ursprünglich eine (vielleicht sogar absichtlich humoristische) Kontraktion aus "Schlünde" und "Münder" ist... nur so als Hypothese...

Comment: Ach nee. Es kommt doch auch in anderer Umgebung vor: Hier in einem Gebet- und Liederbuch aus dem 19. Jahrhundert: 
*Mein Gott! Tief ins Verderben stürze mich die Eitelkeit, / 
Unendlich banges Sterben ergreift mich nach der Zeit, /
Wenn du mich jenen **Schlündern** des Feuers nicht entreißt, /
Wo Trost und Hoffen schwinden, dem Ort, der Hölle heißt.*

Comment: @Christian: Wenn das in mehreren bekannten Publikationen jedweder Art zu finden wäre (Bücher, Zeitschriften, Zeitungen, Websites, usw.), dann wäre das akzeptabel. Aber wenn das nur einer, den ich nicht einmal kenne oder einschätzen kann, schreibt, habe ich (m.E. zurecht) meine Zweifel, vor allem weil z.B. der Duden wirklich gar nichts über diese Form sagt.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: "viele Schlünder zu füttern" kommt bei meiner Suche nur einmal vor. Das ist doch sehr wenig. Mehrere Vorkommnisse würden den Ausdruck dann schon etwas glaubwürdiger machen.

Comment: @IQV: Wenn man dann mal nachsieht, wo "Schlünder" vorkommt, dann sieht man nur Eigennamen. Nicht sehr überzeugend.

Comment: @Rudy Velthuis   Ich würde für mehr Skepsis gegenüber Google plädieren. Es kommt ja völlig auf das Textkorpus an, das der Googlemaschinerie zugrundeliegt. Zum Beispiel der Fund (oben zitiert) mit dem LIed aus einem evangelischen Gesangbuch: das hat Google sich zusammengesucht aus einer Bibliothek deutscher Einwanderer in den USA. Ich gehe stark davon aus, dass Google durchaus noch keinen repräsentativen Querschnitt deutscher Literatur (vor allem des 19. Jahrhunderts) zusammengescannt hat. Viele alte *Schlünder* mögen heute nur auf Papier, nicht aber in Elektronenform zu finden sein.

Comment: @Christian: In alten Schriften werden viele Sachen anders oder gar (verglichen mit der heutigen Schreibweise) falsch geschrieben. Ich finde das kein überzeugendes Argument. *Schlünder* klingt für mich immer noch wie Lokalkolorit oder Mundart.

Comment: Aber ich sehe, dass das wieder in einen Chat getrieben werden soll. Ist nicht so wichtig.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Mein Hinweis auf das Google Ngram sollte deine Skepsis unterstützen, die ich vollständig teile. Ich bezweifle ebenfalls stark, dass "Schlünder" der korrekte Plural von Schlund ist. Meiner Ansicht nach ist er das allerhöchstens umgangssprachlich. Und das Ngram zeigt ziemlich eindrücklich, wie selten (relativ und absolut) es genutzt wurde.

Answer (score 2):

> der Irrtum, die Irrtümer

I doubt such a memorizing rule helps as nouns that follow your description are numerous, not just twelve, and they come in all three genders:

> der Reichtum, die Reichtümer
>
> der Mann, die Männer
>
> das Band, die Bänder
>
> das Bad, die Bäder
>
> das Blatt, die Blätter
>
> das Brauchtum, die Brauchtümer (BUT e.g. das Votum, die Voten  (it is a foreign word from latin))
>
> das Kalb, die Kälber

Both singular and plural with -er:

> der Vater, die Väter
>
> die Mutter, die Mütter

And of course add all the compounds.

Comment: i know that these words are not only in the masculine gender, they are numerous in other genders, but they are pretty rare in masculine

Comment: Bisher sind wir bei 11 Maskulinen. Also scheint die Behauptung zu stimmen? Aber eines fehlt noch...

Comment: Allein die Worte mit -tum am Ende sind schon eine ganze Gruppe, die keinem Schema folgt.

Comment: @Janka   **Der Reichtum**, **der Irrtum**, okay... aber **das Siechtum**, **das Christentum**... könnte es sein, dass die Zahl der männlichen *-tümer* eben doch begrenzt ist? Ich denke, wenn man neue *-tümer* schafft, werden sie in der Regel sächlich sein?

Comment: *»Band, Bad, Blatt, Kalb«* and *»Mutter«* are not really **masculine**.

Comment: @Janka: Die einzigen männlichen Nomen, die auf *-tum* enden, sind *Irrtum* und *Reichtum*. Mehr gibt es von dieser Sorte nicht.

Answer (score 2):

Two more masculines:

> - der Balg / die Bälger (also: *das* Balg)
> - der Wald / die Wälder

Answer (score 2):

Adding to what was already mentioned:

> - der Gott - die Götter
> - der Rand - die Ränder
> - der Wurm - die Würmer
> - der Mund - die Münder
> - der Strauch - die Sträucher